# How to find all documents in couchDB using ektrop library

Tags: couchdb, ektorp

I have gone through all the blogs available for the ektrop library and also the source code of the library.I have found that **get(class obj,String id)** function is available but If I use this function then only one document will be returned according to the id given.So **I want to read all the changed documents present in the bucket**.How Can I achieve this.Thanks in advance any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for the _all_docs endpoint.

```
ViewQuery q = new ViewQuery().allDocs().includeDocs(true);

List<Sofa> bulkLoaded = db.queryView(q, Sofa.class);
```

You can find more detailed information in the [api](https://helun.github.io/Ektorp/reference_documentation.html#d100e642)

Answer (score 0):

Hello all I have got the answer the question asked by me above.Here is the steps by which you can get the all documents or simply the result of _changes API is used.

1. Integrate the Ektorp library into your project.
2. Use the follwing code to get the all document.

   ```
                HttpClient httpClient = new StdHttpClient.Builder()
               .url("http://localhost:5984/")
               .build();
       CouchDbInstance dbInstance = new StdCouchDbInstance(httpClient);
       CouchDbConnector db = new StdCouchDbConnector("my_database", dbInstance);
       ChangesCommand.Builder builder = new ChangesCommand.Builder();
       ChangesCommand changesCommand =builder.build() ;
       List<DocumentChange> documentChangeList=db.changes(changesCommand);

       for(int i=0;i<documentChangeList.size()-1;i++) {
           System.out.println(documentChangeList.get(i).getId());
       }
   ```

Comment: Be careful: With this code you get "all the changes" (`_changes`) an not "all the documents" (`_all_docs`). In a way, the first set includes the second set. But, the more your documents get updated, the less your code will be efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I have updated my question sorry there was mistake in question.